# Editing multiple records in entity with SQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to PHP and seem to be following a half-baked tutorial. Which is incredibly frustrating and now I'm desperate to solve this.

I am trying to update multiple records in multiple entities with the one form submission. My PHP function is below.

```
function updateFixture() {

  global $server, $db, $dbUser, $dbKey, $message;

  try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $server . ";dbname=" . $db, $dbUser, $dbKey);
    $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE Date SET date=:date WHERE dateID=:dateID");

    $sql -> bindValue(":dateID", $_POST["dateID"]);
    $sql -> bindValue(":date", $_POST["date"]);

    $sql = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE Score SET homeScore=:homeScore1, awayScore=:awayScore1 WHERE scoredID=:scores1");

    $sql -> bindValue(":scores1", $_POST["scores1"]);
    $sql -> bindValue(":homeScore1", $_POST["homeScore1"]);
    $sql -> bindValue(":awayScore1", $_POST["awayScore1"]);

    $sql = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE Score SET homeScore=:homeScore2, awayScore=:awayScore2 WHERE scoredID=:scores2");

    $sql -> bindValue(":scores2", $_POST["scores2"]);
    $sql -> bindValue(":homeScore2", $_POST["homeScore2"]);
    $sql -> bindValue(":awayScore2", $_POST["awayScore2"]);

    $sql = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE Score SET homeScore=:homeScore3, awayScore=:awayScore3 WHERE scoredID=:scores3");

    $sql -> bindValue(":scores3", $_POST["scores3"]);
    $sql -> bindValue(":homeScore3", $_POST["homeScore3"]);
    $sql -> bindValue(":awayScore3", $_POST["awayScore3"]);

    $sql = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE Score SET homeScore=:homeScore4, awayScore=:awayScore4 WHERE scoredID=:scores4");

    $sql -> bindValue(":scores4", $_POST["scores4"]);
    $sql -> bindValue(":homeScore4", $_POST["homeScore4"]);
    $sql -> bindValue(":awayScore4", $_POST["awayScore4"]);

    $result = $sql -> execute();

    if ($result) {
      $message = "Customer record was updated";
    } else {
      $message = "The Customer record was not updated";
    }
  }

  catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "<div class='notification container'><p>An error occured: " . $e -> getMessage() . "</p></div>";
  }

  $conn = null;
}

if (isset($_POST["updateFixture"])) {
  updateFixture($_POST["dateID"]);
}
```

This seems to work fine with the one `prepare` statement being made to the `Score` entity. When I add the additional three `prepare` statements is when this functions fails.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `execute()` for each `prepare()`, you are just calling it once at the end.

So...

```
$sql = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE Date SET date=:date WHERE dateID=:dateID");

$sql -> bindValue(":dateID", $_POST["dateID"]);
$sql -> bindValue(":date", $_POST["date"]);

$result = $sql -> execute();

$sql = $conn -> prepare("UPDATE Score SET homeScore=:homeScore1, awayScore=:awayScore1 WHERE scoredID=:scores1");
```

etc.